# Удаление записей базы данных одним запросом

Tags: sql

В таблице имеются более 3т записей с одинаковым содержанием, как можно их удалить одним запросом? Допустим, если в таблице в одном из полей есть одинаковый текст.

Answer (score 3):

Пусть основная таблица table1 содержит поля: id (int not null auto_increment primary key), data (varchar). В поле data есть дубликаты. Удалить дубликаты можно например так:

1. cоздать новую таблицу table2 (копия таблицы table1):

   insert into table2 (select * from table1);
2. удалить дубликаты из основной таблицы:

   delete from table1 where id not in (select min(id) from table2 group by data);
3. удалить таблицу table2:

   drop table table2;

А можно сразу в новую таблицу выбрать только уникальные по полю data записи из таблицы table1.